# How can I extract some column from the dataset in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset, extract

```
a = dataset({'a' 'b' 'c' 'e' 'h'}',[1 2 3 11 17]', [2 3 4 5 6]',...
   'VarNames',{'Key1' 'Var1' 'test'})

a = 

    Key1       Var1    test
    'a'         1      2   
    'b'         2      3   
    'c'         3      4   
    'e'        11      5   
    'h'        17      6
```

I want to make a new dataset with some data in a.

just like `b = a.VarNames=={'Key1', 'test'}`

Thus

```
b = 

    Key1    test
    'a'       2   
    'b'       3   
    'c'       4   
    'e'       5   
    'h'       6
```

How can I make b?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
b = dataset(a.Key1, a.test, 'VarNames', {'Key1','test'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

> > b= [a(:,1) a(:,3)]

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't hardcode the key names, I'd use the following:

```
%% Input:
a=dataset({'a' 'b' 'c' 'e' 'h'}',[1 2 3 11 17]',[2:6]','VarNames',{'Key1' 'Var1' 'test'});
extract_keys = {'Key1' 'Var1'};

%% subset extraction:
keys = get(a,'VarNames');
extract_idxs = cellfun(@(str) find(strcmpi(keys ,str),1),extract_keys,'uni',false);
if any(cellfun(@isempty,extract_idxs(:)))
    warning('Dataset:subset_extraction', 'Key mismatch');
end
extract_idxs = cell2mat(extract_idxs);

b = a(:,extract_idxs);
```

If keys are not found in the original dataset, they're omitted from the resulting dataset.
The warning might also be erased if you're sure that the keys match all the time. You can even throw it in a one-liner if you don't need the warning:

```
b=a(:,cell2mat(cellfun(@(str) find(strcmpi(get(a,'VarNames'),str),1),extract_keys,'uni',false)));
```